# Create a JS multidimensional array from string

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I would like to create a miltidimentional array as follows so

```
var multi-arr = [
                  ["A,2,5"], 
                  ["B,4,4"], 
                  ["C,4,4"]
                ]
```

from string values gotten from the database using ajax.

string data gotten from db delimited by #

```
var string = "A,2,5# B,4,4# C,4,4";
```

I split the string by a '#' delimiter

```
arr1=string.split(/\s*\#\s*/g);
```

creating the array below

```
var arr = ["A,2,5", "B,4,4", "C,4,4"];
```

I want to further split the items in the above array 
using the comma ',' as a delimiter and create a multidimensional array

My problem is the loop only pushes in the last item in the array

```
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {  
        var arr2 = [];
        arr2[i]=arr2.push(arr1[i].split(/\s*\,\s*/g));
    }

console.log(arr2);
```

What am i doing wrong?
or what can i do better?

Comment: why not rewrite it to JSON and just parse that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The var statement should be **outside** the for loop and you don't need to do the assignment and the push.

```
var i;
var string = "A,2,5# B,4,4# C,4,4";
var arr1 = string.split("#");
var arr2 = [];
for (i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
        arr2[i]=arr1[i].split(",");
}   

console.log(arr2);
```

As suggested by Mike 'Pomax' - you could return the data from the server as JSON.  If you're using PHP, that can be done like so:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($queryResult);
exit;
```

Comment: That's what i was doing wrong. But i'll use Mike 'Pomax' s method.

Comment: just remember not to trust your server's response (becaue 404s, 500s, etc), and use a try/catch, because if you're feeding data to JSON.parse() without knowing for certain what's in it (like in my answer), it can throw and cause your script to error out.

Comment: For fun - you can compare the performance of these solutions: http://jsperf.com/string-to-multi-array.  Performance will likely vary on different data sets, one one of these solutions has an additional check on the content of the array.

Answer (score 4):

You could split it, but you have all the delimiters in place anyway, just rewrite your string to be JSON-conformant and run it through `JSON.parse()`:

```
// base string
var str = "A,2,5# B,4,4# C,4,4";

// quote text data. If the array was plain number data, we don't even need this step.
var quoted = str.replace(/([a-zA-Z]+)/g,'"$1"');

// rewrite to JSON form for a nested array
var jsonStr = "[[" + quoted.replace(/#/g,'],[') + "]]";

// done, just tell the JSON parser to do what it needs to do.
var arr = JSON.parse(jsonStr);
```

And that's it, `arr` is now the nested array `[["A",2,5],["B",4,4],["C",4,4]]`.

Answer (score 2):

This should work

```
var str = "A,2,5# B,4,4# C,4,4";
var arr = str.split(/\s*\#\s*/g);
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {  
        arr[i]=arr[i].split(/\s*\,\s*/g);
    }
console.log(arr)
```

In your solution `var arr2 = [];` needs to be outside the `for` loop, or it gets redefined everytime. However, we don't really need to define a separate var and simply update the original array.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple solution that should work on modern browsers:

```
var string = "A,2,5# B,4,4# C,4,4";
var multiArray = string.split(/\s*\#\s*/g).map(function(substr) {
  return [substr];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

From your current `arr` variable - `["A,2,5", "B,4,4", "C,4,4"]` - you can create your `multi_arr` variable like so:

```
var multi_arr = [];

arr.forEach(function(a) {
  multi_arr.push([a]);
});
```

Keep in mind, this will create the array exactly as the example of what you were looking for, which was this:

```
var multi-arr = [
                  ["A,2,5"], 
                  ["B,4,4"], 
                  ["C,4,4"]
                ]
```

If you want each of the items in the inner arrays to be split as well, this will work for you:

```
var multi_arr = [];

arr.forEach(function(a) {
  multi_arr.push(a.split(','));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to loop over each element in the array again after your first split. I would use `Array.prototype.map` as it will return you a new array without mutating the original.

I also did a check to see if the value in the inner array was a number. if it was it is parsed to an actual number.

```js
var arr = ["A,2,5", "B,4,4", "C,4,4"];

console.log(arr);

var multidimensional = arr.map(function(item) {
  // you need to split the elements in your array
  return item.split(/,/).map(function(val) {
    // you may as well check if it's a string or a Number
    return parseIfNumber(val);
  })
});

console.log(multidimensional);

// helper functioon
function parseIfNumber(val) {
  return /^[0-9.-]+$/.test(val) 
    ? Number(val) 
    : val;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://codepen.io/synthet1c/pen/WrQapG.js"></script>
```